# R Delete all rows in dataframe based on index

Tags: r

I have a list of indices that I know I want to remove from my data frame.

Normally I can do this easily with just writing out the names but I don't understand why the following command works when I want to keep the rows I am deleting:

```
str(data)
'data.frame':   180 obs. of  624 variables:
$ Sites                                              : chr  "SS0501_1" "SS0570_1" "SS0609_1" "SS0645_1" ...
$ LandUse                                            : chr  "Urban" "Urban" "Urban" "Urban" ...
.
.
.

f_pattern <- "SS2371|SS1973|SS1908|SS1815|SS1385|SS1304" # find index names in data frame using partial site names
get_full_id <- data[grep(f_pattern, rownames(data)),] # get the full site names (these are indices in the data frame)

data <- data[!get_full_id$Sites,] # DOES NOT WORK
Error in !check$Sites : invalid argument type
```

However, it does work if I pull these sites out.

```
data <- data[get_full_id$Sites,] # Works fine, I get a dataframe with 6 rows...the ones I don't want to keep.
str(data)
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  624 variables:
$ Sites                                              : chr  "SS1908_1" "SS1973_1" "SS1304_2" "SS1385_2" ...
$ LandUse                                            : chr  "Urban" "Rural" "Rural" "Urban" ...
.
.
```

I don't understand why the reverse with "!" won't work at all?

Comment: I guess your `grep` should be based on 'Sites' column instead of `rownames`? Also, the `get_full_id` (if you have rownames, is a data.frame and it cannot be used for indexing Probably you want `data[setdiff(data$Sites, get_full_id$Sites),]` or if there are row.names, use `-` i.e. `data[-get_full_id$Sites,]`

Comment: ! is a setdiff operator in the context of the tidyverse functions and evaluation of columns, it isn't in the context of the standard evaluation which evals from the bottom to the top. The "reverse" of a character (i guess it is) doesn't exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the dataset have rownames, then we may need `-` instead of `!` (if it is an exact match (- not clear as the rownames are not showed))

```
data[-get_full_id$Sites,]
```

because the negation works on a logical vector.  Here, we are asking to return the rows that doesn't match the rownames in 'Sites' column.  If we want to use `!`, create a logical vector

```
data[!row.names(data) %in% get_full_id$Sites,]
```

This also works only if there is an exact match

---

Also, this can be done directly

```
data[-grep(f_pattern, rownames(data)),]
```

Or use `invert = TRUE`

```
data[grep(f_pattern, rownames(data), invert = TRUE),]
```

Comment: Negation alone did not work but your second line of code did work, by calling the %in% module. I still am not quite understanding why one way works but the reverse doesn't> Wouldn't both forms be creating a logical vector?

Comment: Ah your update makes sense - because I am using a substring to find the full names then negation wouldn't work. Still not sure why calling the get_full_ids$Sites works fine but "!" in front of it doesn't do the same thing but reverse.

Comment: @CuriousDude sorry, the issue was that `-` is based on the row.names, and if it is not an exact match, it wouldn't work.  That is the reason the easiest approach is to directly use the `grep` output for subsetting instead of getting the subset

Comment: @CuriousDude The reason is `get_full_id$Sites with %in% match` those rowsnames from 'data', but we want the opposite of those matches i.e. we want to negate the TRUE -> FALSE and FALSE -> TRUE, (`!` does the negation)